# Netbeans insert code

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins, ide

How would one go about creating a plugin or something of the like that would add to the 'insert code' dialog of the context menu the ability to create a copy constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this tutorial will help you:

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-generator.html